# How can I limit barcode scanner to once?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, google-mlkit

I try to code a barcode scanner with Jetpack Compose and Google ML Kit. I use ImageAnalysis with the STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST and call a class BarCodeAnalyzer who initialize and create the barcodeScanner.

But when I scan a barcode, my code detect two time the same barcode and open two screens.

So how can I pause scan ? Or stop the imageAnalysis when I found a barcode ?

**AndroidView**

```
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        val previewView = PreviewView(context)
        val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
        val selector = CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
            .build()
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
        val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setTargetResolution(
                Size(
                    previewView.width,
                    previewView.height
                )
            )
            .setBackpressureStrategy(STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            .build()
        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
            BarCodeAnalyzer { result ->
                code = result
                navController.navigate(
                    Screen.FormProduct.route + "?barcode=$code"
                )
            }
        )

        try {
            cameraProviderFuture.get().bindToLifecycle(
                lifecycleOwner,
                selector,
                preview,
                imageAnalysis
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        previewView
    },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
)
```

**BarCodeAnalyzer**

```
class BarCodeAnalyzer(
    private val onBarCodeScanned: (String) -> Unit,
) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    var currentTimestamp: Long = 0

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val options = BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
            .setBarcodeFormats(
                Barcode.FORMAT_EAN_13,
                Barcode.FORMAT_EAN_8
            )
            .build()

        val image = imageProxy.image

        if (image != null) {
            val inputImage = InputImage.fromMediaImage(image, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)

            val scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(options)

            scanner.process(inputImage)
                .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                    if (barcodes.isNotEmpty()) {
                        barcodes.firstOrNull()?.rawValue?.let { barcode ->
                            Log.i(TAG, "Barcode : $barcode")
                            onBarCodeScanned(barcode)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    imageProxy.close()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to debounce your image processing function so that it only runs once when called multiple times within a period of time

Comment: I must debounce the "imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer" or inside the "BarCodeAnalyzer" ? 
Thanks

Comment: You can also split the declaration and assignment of your onSuccessListener lambda so that you can unsubscribe from the listener when you detect the barcode the first time.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, in my BarCodeAnalyzer I created a variable firstCall initialize at true then where a barcode was founded I pass firstCall to false like this :

```
class BarCodeAnalyzer(
    private val onBarCodeScanned: (String) -> Unit,
) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    private var firstCall = true

    ...

    scanner.process(inputImage)
        .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
             if (barcodes.isNotEmpty()) {
                 if (firstCall) {
                      firstCall = false
                       barcodes.firstOrNull()?.rawValue?.let { barcode ->
                       onBarCodeScanned(barcode)
                 }
             }
         }
    }

   ...
}
```

Comment: You did the good job by using Flag :)

Comment: simple solution good one !!!